# How to use Set method to get unique dates from List of objects in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a class named TransactionModel where I have taken two property
double amount,
DateTime date,

Now I want to get all unique dates from List with the help of SET method..

and expecting result is 2023-01-22 and 2023-01-23 but it is showing all...looks like due to time values..

so how to use SET based on date only(Year month day)

I have used following way

```
final dates = datalist.map((e) => e.date).toSet();
```

```
2023-01-22 22:32:16.482
2023-01-22 22:32:25.869
2023-01-22 22:32:33.709
2023-01-22 22:32:45.509
2023-01-22 22:32:50.785
2023-01-22 22:32:57.557
2023-01-22 22:33:31.553
2023-01-23 12:06:01.882
2023-01-23 21:41:05.551
2023-01-23 21:41:18.911
```

Answer (score 1):

It is solved with the help of StackOverflow questions

Using DateFormat

```
  final dates = datalist.map((e) => DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(e.date)).toSet();
```